# how to check database user existence? (DataBase independently)

Tags: java, database

Does anyone know a way (in java) to check if specific user exists in DB? It has to work on the most Databases

Comment: There isn't going to be a DBMS-independent way to check that.

Comment: just connect to the database? Try first with a user you know exists (to make sure that you can reach the databse) and the with the user to test. If the second one fails it can be assumed that this user has no connect permission, which should mean that he does not exist (depends on how you configure your databases).

Comment: oers, what if password is wrong? I am rather looking for a library with method which can deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the system tables of database (Oracle, MySql, etc..)

For example, in MySQL you can try this:

```
select * from mysql.user;
```

Regards

Comment: I mentioned I care about Database independence. It means that i am looking for a library or something which deal with many databases.

Answer (score 0):

It couldn't be database-independent, but it can be at a certain view. I mean you can expose an interface to others, and implement the db-dependent logic in your implementation. So it's db-independent for others now.

Here is an example(java):

```
public boolean exists(name, password)
```

and the implementation should be like this:

```
if (Oracle) {check with Oracle rules}
if (MySQL) {check with MySQL rules}
...
```

So others/you can call `exists` method to check if an user exist, without caring for the database. ^-^

If there is such a tool, it must be the same way as above.

Comment: "If there is such a tool, it must be the same way as above." , I know how can implement it, but I want to avoid implementing it by myself, because someone have already done it. probably